# While using trunc() function, the correct value is not returned

Tags: r, truncate

```r
> a = pi
> a
[1] 3.141593
> trunc(a,3)
[1] 3
```

Ideally, it should be trunc(a,3) returning 3.141

Why is it happening?

Comment: Hi Midhun, if you want to show several lines of code, you can write a line with three backticks, then your code lines, then another line with three backticks. There might be smarter ways - I am only an occasional user here :-)

Answer (score 2):

`trunc` in R always returns an *integer* value. If you want to cut off 3 decimals after the point, you could multiply by 10^3, apply `trunc`, and then divide by 10^3 again. In your example

```r
a <- pi
trunc(a * 1e3) / 1e3
```

If you need this often, you can make your own function. Here is a very simple example that does not catch errors:

```r
# define the function
decimaltrunc <- function(x, digits = 0) trunc(x * 10^digits) / 10^digits
# then use it:
decimaltrunc(pi, 3)
```

happy R programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default `trunc()` function has only one argument. This argument is truncated, and all other arguments are ignored. For example:

```
> trunc(2.2, 6.3, 4.4, "hi")
[1] 2
```

Note that the argument can also be a vector like `trunc(c(2.2, 6.3, 4.4))` in which case all elements of the vector are truncated and a vector is returned, but it is still just a single argument. So the functionality of specifying the number of significant digits is not implemented, and you would need to multiply with a power of 10 as in the answer by Ute.

The reason that the function does not give an error when more than one argument is supplied, like `ceiling(1.8, 2.6)` for example (which *does* give an error), is that `trunc()` is defined with the special argument `...` that allows to easily extend the original definition when implementing custom classes that have additional arguments for the extended function. From the [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html) on the rounding functions:

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> ceiling(x)  
> floor(x)  
> trunc(x, ...)  
>  
> round(x, digits = 0)  
> signif(x, digits = 6)
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
> `x`: a numeric vector. Or, for `round` and `signif`, a complex vector.
> `digits`: integer indicating the number of decimal places (`round`) or significant digits (`signif`) to be used. For `round`, negative values are allowed (see 'Details').
> `...` arguments to be passed to methods.

The normal use case for this is to first do some operation on the data to make it suitable for the original function, which is then called using the built-in `NextMethod()`. In this call all the arguments are supplied to the original function, which therefore needs to ignore any arguments that are not used, like `printchar` in the example below.

MCVE:

```
myobject = 5.4321
class(myobject) <- "MyClass"
trunc.MyClass <- function(x, printchar = "*", ...) {
   paste0(printchar, NextMethod(), printchar)
}
trunc(myobject, printchar = "#")
```

Result:

```
[1] "#5#"
```

Compare to `ceiling()`, which does not have the `...` argument in the original definition:

```
myobject = 5.4321
class(myobject) <- "MyClass"

ceiling.MyClass <- function(x, printchar = "*", ...) {
   paste0(printchar, NextMethod(), printchar)
}
ceiling(myobject, printchar = "#")
```

In this case the `NextMethod()` call results in an error:

```
Error in ceiling(myobject, printchar = "#") : 
  2 arguments passed to 'ceiling' which requires 1
```

Comment: This is a really good and truly comprehensive explanation for "*why*"  one can end up expecting the wrong thing from an R function ... and why R syntax is meaningful anyway :-)